# Android set radius programatically to ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

Can I set a radius programmatically to a ShapeDrawable?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27980783/4148757

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You can do it like this:

```
public static void customView(View v, int backgroundColor, int   borderColor)
{
  GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
  shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
  shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
  shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
  shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
  v.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
}
```

> You can use this function throughout your app and can put border and background color of your choice.

Comment: I don't see any use of ShapeDrawable?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable) btnCallnow.getBackground();
        final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_id);
        shape.setCornerRadius(5.0f);
```

Comment: I don't see any use of ShapeDrawable?

Comment: Shape_id is id of custom drawable shape.