# Add left corner to an ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I would like to add round corner to left corners of my ImageView so I tried with that :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/teal_blue" />
<corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0.01dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0.01dp"/>
</shape>
```

If I change any BottomRight/left or TopRight nothing happens but if I change the topLeftRadius, each corner is rounded.

I do not understand why, any advice ?

Comment: According to this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122199/how-do-i-set-the-rounded-corner-radius-of-a-color-drawable-using-xml  If you set any of the corners to 0dp, they ALL change to that.